Binary Bomb Phase4
Im stuck on this binary bomb and need help. I tried to trace the code but I am genuinely lost. Could someone help guide me to finding the solution? All I know is it is asking for two number inputs such as 1 2 and that the first input must be less than 14 (40106a).
I came to the solution of 3 1 however it is wrong. I'd like to explain how I got to it so someone can enlighten my wrongdoings.
With the first input being 3, the following is passed into the function: func4(3, 0, 14).
It first calculate the midpoint which is (0+14) // 2 = 7.
Since 3 < 7 it jumps to call the function again with new parameters of func(3, 0, 6).
I got the 6 as the upper bound is now midpoint - 1 = 6. With the new parameters the midpoint is now (0+6) // 2 = 3. Since 3 == 3, it exits the recursion

000000000040100b <func4>:
  40100b:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  40100f:   89 d1                   mov    %edx,%ecx
  401011:   29 f1                   sub    %esi,%ecx
  401013:   89 c8                   mov    %ecx,%eax
  401015:   c1 e8 1f                shr    $0x1f,%eax
  401018:   01 c8                   add    %ecx,%eax
  40101a:   d1 f8                   sar    %eax
  40101c:   01 f0                   add    %esi,%eax
  40101e:   39 f8                   cmp    %edi,%eax
  401020:   7f 0c                   jg     40102e <func4+0x23>
  401022:   7c 18                   jl     40103c <func4+0x31>
  401024:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  401029:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  40102d:   c3                      retq   
  40102e:   8d 50 ff                lea    -0x1(%rax),%edx
  401031:   e8 d5 ff ff ff          callq  40100b <func4>
  401036:   8d 44 00 01             lea    0x1(%rax,%rax,1),%eax
  40103a:   eb ed                   jmp    401029 <func4+0x1e>
  40103c:   8d 70 01                lea    0x1(%rax),%esi
  40103f:   e8 c7 ff ff ff          callq  40100b <func4>
  401044:   01 c0                   add    %eax,%eax
  401046:   eb e1                   jmp    401029 <func4+0x1e>

0000000000401048 <phase_4>:
  401048:   48 83 ec 18             sub    $0x18,%rsp
  40104c:   48 8d 4c 24 08          lea    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
  401051:   48 8d 54 24 0c          lea    0xc(%rsp),%rdx
  401056:   be 1e 27 40 00          mov    $0x40271e,%esi
  40105b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  401060:   e8 cb fb ff ff          callq  400c30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
  401065:   83 f8 02                cmp    $0x2,%eax
  401068:   75 07                   jne    401071 <phase_4+0x29>
  40106a:   83 7c 24 0c 0e          cmpl   $0xe,0xc(%rsp)
  40106f:   76 05                   jbe    401076 <phase_4+0x2e>
  401071:   e8 5e 06 00 00          callq  4016d4 <explode_bomb>
  401076:   ba 0e 00 00 00          mov    $0xe,%edx
  40107b:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
  401080:   8b 7c 24 0c             mov    0xc(%rsp),%edi
  401084:   e8 82 ff ff ff          callq  40100b <func4>
  401089:   83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
  40108c:   75 07                   jne    401095 <phase_4+0x4d>
  40108e:   83 7c 24 08 01          cmpl   $0x1,0x8(%rsp)
  401093:   74 05                   je     40109a <phase_4+0x52>
  401095:   e8 3a 06 00 00          callq  4016d4 <explode_bomb>
  40109a:   48 83 c4 18             add    $0x18,%rsp
  40109e:   c3                      retq   


AFAICT, the second input (which is scanned into 8(%rsp)) isn't passed to func4.  This looks like compiler-generated code, so we can assume the standard x86-64 SysV calling convention, so a 4th arg would go in ECX not the stack.  Seems weird, like they might as well have just had it take one integer; the second is a freebie since they're not passing a pointer to it either.  Anyway, we can see phase_4 passing 3 args to func4, which also calls itself recursively.  I'm not going to do your homework for you, but hopefully that helps.

@PeterCordes Thank you for the help, so based on the code, the second input is given as 1 and now I have to find the correct first input that would work in func4? The three arguments as follows: first_input(%edi), 0(%esi), 14(%edx)?

That's correct.

I came to the solution of 3 1 however it is wrong. I'd like to explain how I got to it so someone can enlighten my wrongdoings. with the first input being 3, the following is passed into the function: func4(3, 0, 14).  It first calculate the midpoint which is
(0+14) // 2 = 7. Since 3 < 7 it jumps to call the function again with new parameters of func(3, 0, 6). I got the 6 as the upper bound is now midpoint - 1 = 6. With the new parameters the midpoint is now (0+6) // 2 = 3. Since 3 == 3, it exits the recursion.

[edit] your question with those extra details.  An attempt makes it a much more specific question, and possible to answer without just doing your homework for you.  (How do I ask and answer homework questions?).  Also, an edit will let you format it on multiple lines so it's more readable.  Also, have you tried using GDB?  You could set a breakpoint at func4 and display the 3 incoming arg registers so you can see them at each level of recursion.

Thank you, after using the debugger it was found that the answer was indeed correct. Thank you for your help Peter, you are teaching me alot. For some reason the server did not like that input last night but now it works.
